# setInterval inside ng-controller won't work without $http

Tags: angularjs

I got this strange problem. For some bizzare reason, my `setInterval` won't work without `$http.get()` inside it. Currently, `$http` is set as a dependency for controller hosting said interval. But if I get rid of them (both dependency and call itself) `setInterval` stops working. I have no idea how to fix this.

Here is code for the controller

```
main.controller('timeCtrl', function($scope, $http, clockService) {
    $scope.time = clockService.timeBase();
    setInterval(function() {
        $http.get();
        $scope.time = clockService.timeBase();
    }, 500);
});
```

After removing the dependancy, it looks like this

```
main.controller('timeCtrl', function($scope, clockService) {
    $scope.time = clockService.timeBase();
    setInterval(function() {
        $scope.time = clockService.timeBase();
    }, 500);
});
```

But it doesn't work. What the heck is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval` is JS function and it won't trigger digest cycle so angular won't see that something have changed.
try using it's angular version - [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

P.S. when a promise is resolved it triggers digest cycle so that call to $http did the job, but it's obviously not the way to do what you want